# Why doesn't convertDateTime support Instant

Tags: jsf, timestamp

Why doesn't JSF's convertDateTime support [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html)? It supports all other ["new" Date and Time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) but not Instant. Which I wanted to use for all timestamps in my platform. E.g. for the creation and edit date/time of forum posts. These dates would all be stored in UTC and formatted on the frontend depending on the users timezone.

I could write another converter. But first I would like to know, if it isn't already supported for a good reason. Or should another DateTime class be used for the described purpose?

I expected to use something like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{post.creationTimestamp}">
  <f:convertDateTime type="Instant" timeZone="#{userBean.timeZone}" dateStyle="long" timeStyle="short"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Where `post.creationTimestamp`is an [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) and `userBean.timeZone`is a [TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).
But this doesn't work, because type Instant isn't supported. One possible solution is:

```
<h:outputText value="#{post.creationTimestamp.atZone(userBean.timeZone.toZoneId())}">
  <f:convertDateTime type="localDateTime" dateStyle="long" timeStyle="short" />
</h:outputText>
```

Which seems a little bit cumbersome.

Comment: Could you provide documentation about your point? I cannot find anything about ```type``` accepting ```"LocalDateTime"```, e.g. in [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/jsf-convertdatetime). Anyways, the problem could be that ```Instant``` is a *timestamp*, while ```convertDateTime``` is logically related to a timezone. Therefore it would be somewhat strange if ```Instant``` was accepted.

Comment: It's supported since JSF 2.3 https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1370

Comment: @PhilippKemkes That link doesn't mention Instant as a supported type.

Comment: @Eward: I was referring to the previous statement that type isn't accepting "LocalDateTime".

Answer (score 1):

The Instant class has no format() method (contrary to LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime). So it would be strange if a JSP tag could format it.

You can convert an Instant object to ZonedDateTime with [atZone()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#atZone(java.time.ZoneId)), then you will be able to format it.